# Android Remoteviews for expanded notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-remoteview

The expanded notifications introduced in Jelly Bean allows adding actions. The actions appear as buttons in a row. If I wanted to modify this with my own custom view I would consider a remoteview.

Do expanded notifications allow for remoteviews? I can only find examples of remoteviews being used in simple notifications before the expanded notifications existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/ has the answer in the Custom View at the end.

> So what if the rich notification styles don’t provide you with the
>   layout you need?  Easy, just create your own layout and pass it to the
>   builder.  One little fact to retain is that notifications use remote
>   views, which means you need to create a layout using a RemoteView. 
>   Below is exactly how you would need to create this custom RemoteView.

```
notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
```

Comment: wow, thanks. notification.bigContentView, I would have never guessed to look there for adding a layout through remoteviews